# Convert a list which contains nested arrays(unequal shape) into array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

i have a list which contains nested arrays which have the following:

```
X_train_list=[array([ 6, 8, 6, ..., 6, 10, 1]), 
              array([4, 4, 4, ..., 4, 4, 1]),
              array([[ 1.00000000e+00,  7.94511008e-02,  1.69902773e-01, ...,
                      -2.14712075e-03, -6.92096074e-01,  4.39955591e-01],
                       [ 0.00000000e+00, -2.67692290e+00,  3.91302228e+00, ...,
                        -2.14712075e-03,  7.48800957e-02, -1.24420247e+00],
                       [ 0.00000000e+00, -4.54040642e-01, -1.18029496e-01, ...,
                        -2.14712075e-03,  1.12293567e-01, -6.15915526e-01]])]
```

when i find shape of arrays with:

```
for i in range(0,len(X_train_list):
    print((X_train_list[i]).shape)
```

it shows:

```
 (486952,)
 (486952,)
 (486952, 21)
```

I want to convert this list into an array with:

```
arr_X_train_list = np.asarray(X_train_list)
```

But i get the following error:

```
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (486952,21) into shape (486952)
```

And suggestions on how i can convert my list onto an array?

Comment: The dimensions of items in an array (matrix) must be equal. That is not the case in your data so it is not possible.

Comment: @BramVanroy, I am aware of that. So the only solution is to make the shape of the first two arrays (486952, 21) or convert the last array to(486952,)?

Comment: @Shameendra What is your expected output?

Comment: @a_guest I want something like  (486952,21)(486952,21) (486952, 21) or (486952,)
 (486952,)(486952,). anything which can make the dimentions equal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you want to end with an array of shape (486952, 23). It can be done by adding a dimension to the simple arrays in X_train_list, and concatenating everything on the second axis:

```
resul = np.concatenate([i if len(i.shape) == 2 else i.reshape(len(i), 1)
                        for i in X_train_list], axis=1)
```

Comment: I ended up with an array of shape (486952,34). but this solution also works for me. Thnks a lot!